# PHP: Adding parameters to a url?

Tags: php

If I have the url `mysite.com/test.php?id=1`. The `id` is set when the page loads and can be anything. There could also be others in there such as `?id=1&sort=new`. Is there a way just to add another to the end without finding out what the others are first then building a new url? thanks.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

As an alternative to Kolink's answer, I think I would utilize `http_build_query()`.  This way, if there is nothing in the query string, you don't get an extra `&`.  Although, it won't really make a difference at all.  Kolink's answer is perfectly fine.  I'm posting this mainly to introduce you to `http_build_query()`, as you will likely need it later:

```
http_build_query(array_merge($_GET, array('newvar'=>'123')))
```

Basically, we use [`http_build_query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) to take everything in `$_GET`, and merge it with an array of any other parameters we want.  In this example, I just create an array on the fly, using your example parameter.  In practice, you'll likely have an array like this somewhere already.

Comment: theres no harm in inserting get variables straight into html right?

Comment: @AndyLobel, Of course there is harm!  You should be using `htmlspecialchars()` on **any** PHP variable you echo out to a page.  Otherwise, you open yourself up to XSS.  You don't know what's in that variable, unless you can guarantee it is strictly numeric or something.  Even then, out of caution, I use `htmlspecialchars()` every time.

Comment: ooo right when you say any do you mean like ones that iv'e manually set as well!? thanks ;p

Comment: @AndyLobel, Yes, you should be doing this with everything that is ending up on a page.

Comment: so wait if i went $a = "b"; echo $a; id have to do $a = "b"; echo htmlspecialchars($a); instead? thanks lol il have to look up whatever xss is

Comment: @AndyLobel, In that case, technically it won't make a difference.  But in practice, you'll rarely have a variable where `$a = 'b'`.

Answer (score 3):

```
"?".$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']."&newvar=123";
```

Something like that.

Comment: cheeeerss ;p even tho remeba when the page reloads if you try and click the same link again it will go ?id=1&newvar=123&newvar=123

Answer (score 1):

Use this function: https://github.com/patrykparcheta/misc/blob/master/addQueryArgs.php

```
function addQueryArgs(array $args, string $url)
{
    if (filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)) {
        $urlParts = parse_url($url);
        if (isset($urlParts['query'])) {
            parse_str($urlParts['query'], $urlQueryArgs);
            $urlParts['query'] = http_build_query(array_merge($urlQueryArgs, $args));
            $newUrl = $urlParts['scheme'] . '://' . $urlParts['host'] . $urlParts['path'] . '?' . $urlParts['query'];
        } else {
            $newUrl = $url . '?' . http_build_query($args);
        }
        return $newUrl;

    } else {
        return $url;
    }
}

$newUrl = addQueryArgs(array('add' => 'this', 'and' => 'this'), 'http://example.com/?have=others');
```