# How to add query string/params to url in WordPress?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

I created a custom page template that lists posts from a **"taxonomy"**.

When you click on a post, I want the taxonomy and term to be passed as a parameter in the url as a query string so that i can get the taxonomy on the single post page.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: Adding parameters to a url?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9138297/php-adding-parameters-to-a-url)

Comment: Nope. WordPress has its API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I passed the value as query string to the titles within the taxonomy by using the code below:

```
<?php
  $theTaxonomy = get_taxonomy( get_query_var( 'taxonomy' ) ); 
  $getTaxonomy = $the_tax->labels->name;

  function to_slug($string){
      return strtolower(trim(preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9-]+/', '-', $string)));
  }

  $getTaxonomy;
  $getTaxonomySlug = to_slug($getTaxonomy);
  $getPermalink = esc_url(get_permalink());
  $taxonomyUrl = '?'.'type'.'='.$getTaxonomySlug;
?>

<a href="<?php echo $getPermalink.$taxonomyUrl ?>"></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use add_query_arg, here is [the example](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_query_arg/). Hope this help you

Comment: Hi @Duc Doan, thanks for the advise. I'll look into add_query_arg example